# parse url and separate word in a url path

Tags: php, parsing, url, explode

I'm trying to extract a single bit of data from a URL.

An example of the URL is:

http://website.com/product/category-type-section-detail-1234567589

The data I want to extract is `type` from the path.

I am using:
- parse_url to extract path

```
/product/category-type-section-detail-1234567589
```

- explode to seperate the path

  /product

  /category-type-section-detail-1234567589

How do I extract type?

Answer (score 0):

one way:

```
<?php
$url="http://website.com/product/category-type-section-detail-1234567589";
$x=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$y=explode('-',$x);

echo $y[1]; //type
```

Comment: @PSB glad it help, please learn how to accept answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers